# Task.Run isn't running asynchronously like I had thought it would?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an import operation I'd like to execute on another thread, desiring the UI to respond right away. So, I started down the path and created an action like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<RedirectToRouteResult> ImportAsync(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    var importsRoot = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Imports");
    var path = Path.ChangeExtension(Path.Combine(importsRoot, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()), "txt");

    if (!Directory.Exists(importsRoot))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(importsRoot);
    }

    file.SaveAs(path);

    // start the import process
    await ImportManager.Instance.StartImport(User.Identity.Name);

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

The `ImportManager` now serves two purposes:

1. Handle the import.
2. Notify all clients of the status of the import via SignalR.

The `StartImport` method looks like this:

```
public async Task StartImport(string user)
{
    string[] files;

    var importRoot = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Imports");
    var processingRoot = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Processing");
    var processedRoot = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Processed");

    lock (lockObj)
    {
        //  make sure the "Processing" folder exists
        if (!Directory.Exists(processingRoot))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(processingRoot);
        }

        //  find all of the files available and move them to the "Processing" folder
        files = Directory.GetFiles(importRoot);
        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file);
            if (fileName == null)
            {
                continue;
            }

            File.Move(file, Path.Combine(processingRoot, fileName));
        }

        //  make sure the "Processed" directory exists
        if (!Directory.Exists(processedRoot))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(processedRoot);
        }
    }

    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        //  start processing the files
        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file);
            if (fileName == null)
            {
                continue;
            }

            var processingFileName = Path.Combine(processingRoot, fileName);
            var processedFileName = Path.Combine(processedRoot, fileName);

            var recognizer = new Recognizer(processingFileName);
            recognizer.ProgressChanged += (s, e) => Clients.All.updateImportStatus(e.ProgressPercentage, user);
            recognizer.Recognize(DataManager.GetExclusionPatterns());

            //  move the file to the "Processed" folder
            File.Move(processingFileName, processedFileName);
        }

        Clients.All.importComplete();
    });
}
```

## What's Happening?

Debugging we find that when I hit the `await Task.Run(() =>` it runs synchronously (for a while anyway) because the UI doesn't get the request to redirect to `Index` until say 30K+ lines have been read.

How can I get this to simply execute and forget it? Do I need to use a different approach?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is running asynchronously; but *you are awaiting it*:

```
await ImportManager.Instance.StartImport(User.Identity.Name);

return RedirectToAction("Index");
```

Not waiting; awaiting. The `RedirectToAction` is now a continuation that will be invoked when the other code has been completed.

If you don't want to await; don't `await`. However, you should think about what happens if an error occurs, etc. Do not let your `async` method raise an exception if nobody is going to observe it: bad things.

Comment: So don't `await` the `StartImport` and just execute it, thus the `RedirectToAction` will be the immediate response?

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud No, it will create a continuation at that point, the code after the `await` will be part of that continuation, and will execute when the asynchronous task completes.

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud indeed; I added a final line to explain that, but with an important caveat about exceptions

Comment: @MarcGravell, great! I'm good on exceptions because I handle those silently in the process and handle them later manually.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth it is only a continuation because of the `await`. If the OP removes the `await`, it ceases to be a continuation. In fact, without that `await` there is no need for the action to be an `async` method, either.

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud not in this case you don't - if nobody observes it, your process can implode.

Comment: @MarcGravell, I caught that when removing the await. The action is now a regular `ActionResult` without the `async`; I'm going to try it now.

Comment: @MarcGravell, that worked exactly like I wanted it to! And I think what I'm saying is if exceptions occur during the import, they are handled, and the import continues on. Those exceptions are then reviewed later by hand.

Comment: @MarcGravell Good point, I wasn't explicit enough in my explanation on that.

Answer (score 6):

> How can I get this to simply execute and forget it?

I strongly recommend that you not use "fire and forget" on ASP.NET. The core reason is because ASP.NET manages your application lifetime around request lifetimes. So if you have code executing that is not part of a request, then ASP.NET may take down your application. In the general case, this means that you **cannot depend** on that code actually *executing*.

> Do I need to use a different approach?

The proper solution is to put the work into a reliable queue (e.g., Azure queue or MSMQ) and have an independent backend do the actual processing (e.g., Azure webrole, Azure worker role, or Win32 service). That's a fair amount of work, but it's the only *reliable* solution.

However, if you want to live dangerously and keep the work in-memory in your ASP.NET process, you should register the work with the ASP.NET runtime. You still don't have a *guarantee* that the processing will execute, but it's more *likely*, since ASP.NET is aware of your code. I have a [NuGet package that will do that for you; just use `BackgroundTaskManager.Run` instead of `Task.Run`](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AspNetBackgroundTasks).